# How to reconfigure a non-HA HDFS cluster to HA with minimal/no downtime?

Tags: hadoop, architecture, migration, hdfs, distributed-computing

I have a single namenode HDFS cluster with multiple datanodes that store many terabytes of data. I want to enable high availability on that cluster and add another namenode. What is the most efficient and least error-prone way to achieve that? Ideally that would work without any downtime or with a simple restart.

The two options that came to mind are:

- Edit the configuration of the namenode to facilitate the HA features and restart it. Afterwards add the second namenode and reconfigure and restart the datanodes, so that they are aware that the cluster is HA now.
- Create an identical cluster in terms of data, but with two namenodes. Then migrate the data from the old datanodes to the new datanodes and finally adjust the pointers of all HDFS clients.

The first approach seems easier, but requires some downtime and I am not sure if that is even possible. The second one is somehow cleaner, but there are potential problems with the data migration and the pointers adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this in-place without any down time; a non-HA setup is exactly that, not highly available, and thus *any* code/configuration changes require downtime.

To incur the least amount of downtime while doing this in-place, you probably want to:

- Set up configurations for an HA setup. This includes things like a shared edits directory or journal nodes - see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html or https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html.
- Create a new fsImage using the `hdfs dfsadmin` command. This will ensure that the NameNode is able to restart quickly (on startup, the NN will read the most recent fsImage, then apply all edits from the EditLog that were created after that fsImage).
- Restart your current NameNode and put it into active mode.
- Start the new NameNode in standby.
- Update configurations on DataNodes and restart them to apply.
- Update configurations on other clients and restart to apply.

At this point everything will be HA-aware, and the only downtime incurred was a quick restart of the active NN - equivalent to what you would experience during any code/configuration change in a non-HA setup.

Your second approach should work, but remember that you will need twice as much hardware, and maintaining consistency across the two clusters during the migration may be difficult.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the second point _Create a new fsImage using the hdfs dfsadmin command_? May be I got something wrong, but I want to keep the same data in the cluster. Or you mean to just make sure I clean up the transaction log and make sure that the `fsImage` has the most recent updates?

Comment: Right, sorry, not an entirely new and separate fsImage, just a more recent checkpoint. Created by the dfsadmin (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#dfsadmin) `-saveNamespace` command.

Comment: It seems -saveNamespace requires safe mode. Does it mean we should bring down the cluster to safe mode?